# Get Followers list in Stream-Django

Tags: django, getstream-io, stream-django

I'm using [Stream-Django](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django), Django framework for [getstream.io](https://getstream.io/docs/) for showing feeds.
However, for showing list of followers of a particular user, I'm not able to find any API exposed by **getstream**.

Right now I'm using Django db queries to get the list of followers for a particular user, but am wondering if this can be done via **getstream** apis

Answer (score 1):

If you want users to be able to follow each other but not necessarily follow each other's activities, then you can create a new feed for each user called, for example, "profile" just to handle that. The profile feed needn't contain any activities. Retrieving a list of followers of a user's profile feed is then what you want.

Comment: I dont want the users who follow a given user's feed, I want the users who follow a given user.